# What is a sane logging scheme for Linux Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, logging

Previously, I've deployed a .sh file to run an application I'm developing via this line:

```
./my_qt_application &>> /home/sysadmin/runnable.log
```

Over the next six months my coworker used the application constantly and generated a ~990 GB log file that filled up all available disk space.

I have a couple ideas how to avoid this in the future and save only recent log data, but I'm wondering if there are preexisting logging libraries or utilities that work well with Linux Qt?

Comment: given you're just redirecting to a file, worst case you can use something like apache's log rotator, which can close/open logfiles based on size, elapsed-time, etc...

Comment: Googling that shows results applicable for Apache specifically.  Can you explain how you would configure it for my own log files, or share a link that does that?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I started reading the top links and it might work well.  If you post this as an answer, I'll check mark it.

Comment: You can do better by opening a log file inside your programs code and write to it. That could be a wiser solution to relying on this. You can check the file size, replace it whenever you need to. The possibilities are endless. Just the issue is that you have to rebuild the project and deploy a new version.

Comment: I googled it, and I found how to redirect qDebug, but I rather use a well known utility rather than gamble on potentially buggy new development.  Thanks though!